# missing ']' I don't find any problem in it but it shows me this problem

Tags: bash

I've written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    read fichier1 
    read fichier2
    read fichier3
    if [ -rf "fichier1" && -wf "fichier3" ] || [ -rf "fichier2" && -wf "fichier3" ]
    then
        echo "Vrai"
    else
        echo "FAUX"
    fi
else
    if [ -rf "$1"  && -wf "$3" ] || [ -rf "$2" && -wf "$3" ]
    then
        echo "Vrai"
    else
        echo "FAUX"
    fi
fi
```

I can't it run. There is an error **"missing ']'"** produced.

Comment: Please, format your question before post. It's very hard to examine it without formatting!

Comment: What must to do this conditions: `-rf` and `-wf`?

Comment: Try `man \[`. Especially the advice about `&&` which is not in the expression syntax of `[`.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three flaws in your code:

1. `[ ... && ... ]` should be written as `[ ... ] && [ ... ]`.
2. `-rf` and `-wf` aren't even valid operators. What are you trying to achieve?
3. In line 7, you may want to write `"$fichierN"` instead of `"fichierN"`.

Comment: -rf means that it exists and you can read it

Answer (score 1):

As use Ralph Ronquist mentioned in the comments, your problem is that you are using `&&` within the test expression `[`. Edit your code in the form `if [ -f "fichier1" ] && [ -r "fichier1" ] && [ -w "fichier3" ] ...` and it should get you closer to what you want. Notice that I separated the tests - they will fail when combined like `-rf` ; you need to separate them into separate tests.